# MVC 4 Razor. Partial View Form Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Partial View **EnquiryForm** on my **index** page, I am trying to post data to from Partial View.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EnquiryForm(Booking model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ........
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```

When the form is posted blank validation is not working, Server Side Validation

**Booking Model**

```
public class Booking
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Required" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " - Required")]
    [RegularExpression(".+@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "In-Correct Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Regards
Thanks

Comment: show the viewpage and partial view. If you are using razor view, i suggest you try template.

Comment: yes I am using Razor, any link on how to use template

Comment: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/ this might be help

Comment: what does validation is not working mean? have you tried debugging? is ModelState.IsValid true or false? is your bookingmodel indeed false?

Answer (score 1):

If the validation is false and you redirect the page to "/Home/Index", you will not see the validation message. See blow:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EnquiryForm(Booking model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ........ 
    }
  //  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
      return View();
 }
```

Or you can try the following code:

**Your Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EnquiryForm()
{          
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnquiryForm(Booking model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
   return View();
}
```

**Your EnquiryForm View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EnquiryForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{       
   @Html.Partial("_EnquiryFormPartialView", Model)

   <input type="submit" id="bt_submit"/>
 }
```

**Your Parital view**

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(n => n.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(n => n.Name)
</div>

<div>
  @Html.LabelFor(n => n.Email)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Email)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(n => n.Email)
</div>
```